# Java: Testing inequality of multiple properties between two objects

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, comparison

This is more of a general OOP / Design Pattern question, but I'm working in Java so I'm interested in a Java solution.

Say you've got two objects of the class `Document`...

```
public class Document {
    String project;
    String folder;
    public String getProject() { return project; }
    public String getFolder() { return folder; }
}
```

...and you want to compare one `updatedDoc` to the other `existingDoc`, to call a different function depending on which properties have changed. What is the most efficient way to do that, keeping in mind that values in either object could be null?

Procedurally, I might write something like this:

```
// Convert null values to empty Strings
String updatedProject = updatedDoc.getProject() == null ? "" : updatedDoc.getProject();
String existingProject = existingDoc.getProject() == null ? "" : existingDoc.getProject();
String updatedFolder = updatedDoc.getFolder() == null ? "" : updatedDoc.getFolder();
String existingFolder = existingDoc.getFolder() == null ? "" : existingDoc.getFolder();

boolean projectChanged = !updatedProject.equals(existingProject);
boolean folderChanged = !updatedFolder.equals(existingFolder);

if (projectChanged && folderChanged)
    both();
else if (projectChanged)
    project();
else if (folderChanged)
    folder();
else
    neither();
```

That is very ugly, and if I had to compare a third or fourth property it would get exponentially worse. So what is the best way to do this?

I've seen `Comparable` and `Comparator`, but those seem like they're more for ordering that equality comparisons. Is that still the way to go in this case?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to determine if two are equal, or is your goal to *order* a bunch of them?

Comment: Not trying to order, just trying to decide which method to call (e.g. both() if both properties changed; project() if only project changed; and so on).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "ifology" is not the issue, but your methods. If you truly have four methods to call, then you'll need four separate `if` checks; with a third property, you'll have 8 methods, so the method count is the one which grows exponentially.

You'll either be able to refactor `both()` into `project(); folder();`, or, if it's irreducible, then you have irreducible exponential growth to deal with.

The only possible way to reduce the branching logic in that case is reflection coupled with a good naming convention for the methods, or (less advised) some kind of a Strategy pattern to make the methods first-class, which then allows you to store them in a handy structure and look up the desired method. This will be very similar in spirit to reflection, but will require much more boilerplate.

Comment: Would the strategy pattern be useful here?